# Are there any questions or worksheets available for this topic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions, transformation

I take further math at A levels and this year there has been an addition to the syllabus,

> understand and use relationships between the graphs of $y=f(x),y^2=f(x),y=\frac{1}{f(x)},y=|f(x)|,y=f|x|$

However I have been unable to find any relevant questions from any boards on this specific topic (save for a single question from the specimen paper), if anyone has questions or worksheets that fit this topic (specification/board does not matter) it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The Gelfand book [**Functions and Graphs**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Gelfand+%22functions+and+graphs%22) (see [here](https://www.cimat.mx/ciencia_para_jovenes/bachillerato/libros/functions_and_graphs_gelfand.pdf) in particular) is excellent for this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document is linked here [Special Home Assignment 5](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z3mKw6kawLS6K3D7f6hREuftTMRTMxbo/view?usp=sharing)

It has detailed answers and provides a good practice to visualize the graph of any function.

I hope you would like it.